# Remix Debugger do i need to recompile?

Tags: solidity, remix

If debug transaction and need to change something in code do i need to recompile whole contract or is there a way debugger take into account changes?

Answer (score 0):

By default Remix triggers a compilation each time the current file is changed or another file is selected. If the contract has a lot of dependencies and takes a long time to compile, it is possible to disable the autocompilation.
[Compiling contracts](https://remix.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compile_tab.html)